# How to set a static IP while using a switch?

Tags: networking, windows-10, switch

I have my main router in one room, and a PC in another. I have connected this PC to a [switch](http://a.co/2IOhdIK), which is connected to the [main router](https://www.verizon.com/home/accessories/fios-quantum-gateway/).

I would like to manually set the IP of this PC as seen by the main router. When I use the regular adapter settings, and set my IP, subnet, and gateway, I get "Warning - Multiple default gateways..." (As seen [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/37249c25-c35e-4e4f-806f-c3758fd7576d/warning-multiple-default-gateways-are-intended-to-provide-redundancy-to-a-single-network)). And I think this is not a warning, but an error, because when I look at the `ipconfig \all` output and on the router's management page, the IP address isn't changed.

As far as I remember, this worked fine when direct connected to the router, so I think the switch is screwing it up. Is there any extra steps I can take to make this work, or is there something I'm missing?

Also, the switch works fine when using DHCP, I get an address and I can see the web.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more than one NIC? Check all the NIC settings to see if perhaps another NIC has IP assignments via static or DHCP and perhaps the other NIC has a default gateway assigned to it as well. I've seen this before and I vaguely recall maybe it being related to that.... maybe but it's vague as it's been a while

Comment: Make sure you only have one device with a default gateway.

Comment: "As far as I remember, this worked fine when direct connected to the router, so I think the switch is screwing it up." – no, I have very big doubts about that. Switches don't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Switches don’t cause the type of problem you are referring to. It is no different than plugging it directly in to the router.

What you have actually done is added a static IP address to the wrong adapter on your computer. There may be multiple unused adapters for various reasons on your computer.

First identify, with `ipconfig /all`, which adapter has the currently working DHCP IP address then reconfigure that adapter with the static IP you want to use.

If you have multiple adapters, either wired or wireless connected with a default gateway you might have something hooked up or configured wrong. That information is also identified with `ipconfig /all`. So, there shouldn’t be any problem identifying your network adapters and IP settings that are either correct or incorrect and seeing which other adapters have a default gateway assigned.

Having multiple gateways is not an issue as long as they both get you to the same destinations. For instance, it is not typically a problem to have both a wired and wireless adapter active at the same time with internet access. However, this would make setting and using a static IP address more difficult.